# Can `position: absolute;` change the intercept?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I'm trying to replicate Github's pricing page https://github.com/pricing, specifically the **Most popular** border the *Team plan* has.

If you look at the source code, you'll see that the `<p class="...">Most Popular</p>` has `position: absolute; top: 6px;`. Now, from what I understand, `absolute` positioning takes `x`and `y` values starting from the top left corner of the screen.

How come the `<p class="...">Most popular</p>` tag is perfectly in place with this styling ?

Comment: An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Comment: Okay now it's clear thanks

Answer (score 0):

Understood thanks

> @shakib
> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed). However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Comment: MND's [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#absolute_positioning) and [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.